# Express not sending cookies on production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, backend, production

I have a MERN app in the local server everything is good
But when i doployed the backend
There is no cookies sent to the browser
Why ?
Here is the code for the cookie

```
res.cookie("token", "some value" , { 

     httpOnly: true, 

     maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 20, 
})
```

On local server it's sends a cookie and displayed the browser dev tools and it's working fine